# Hide error on task callback non null

Tags: gulp

I have 2 tasks that should run sequentially and produce error silently so as not to stop the watch. I made one task depends on the other and the first task to have a callback that is called when it finish with an argument to  indicate if successful. Now my problem is that when the call back is called with a non null argument to indicate an error there is an error msg that occurs that is really annoying as it distracts me from the actual error that occured so is there a way to hide that error msg.

Let me show you, what I have is like that

```
gulp.task('stylus', function (cb) {
    var err = null;
    gulp.src('app/**/*.styl')
        .pipe(plumber(function(error){
            err = true;
            gutil.log(error.toString());
        }))
        .pipe(changed('build/css/',{ extension: '.css' }))
        .pipe(stylus())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css/'))
        .on('end',function(){cb(err)});
});
gulp.task('css-concat',['stylus'], function(){  // depends on stylus task
    gulp.src('build/css/**/*.css')
       .pipe(plumber())
       .pipe(concat('app.css'))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['css-concat'], function () { // run css concat first which in trun runs stylus first

    var cssWatch = gulp.watch('app/**/*.styl', ['css-concat']); // watch the same files in our scripts task


    cssWatch.on('change', function (event) {
        if (event.type === 'deleted') {                   // if a file is deleted, delete it from build
            var t = event.path.replace(".styl",".css").replace(/^.+\\app\\/,"build/css/");
           del(t);
        }

    });
});
```

So `css-concat` depends on `stylus` and shouldnt work if `stylus` produces an error, also files are watched and on change call `css-concat` task.

Now here is the error that occurs when `stylus` produce an error (the bold text is the error I am talking about)

```
[03:14:38] Starting 'stylus'...
[03:14:39] ParseError in plugin 'gulp-stylus'
Message:
    D:\angularjs\app\app.styl:1:19
   1| my-color = blue.............
------------------------^
   2| 
   3| body
   4|   background-color my-color

illegal unary "...", missing left-hand operand

[03:14:39] 'stylus' errored after 14 ms
[03:14:39] Error: true
    at formatError (C:\Users\Karim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:161:10)
    at Gulp. (C:\Users\Karim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:187:15)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (D:\angularjs\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at D:\angularjs\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (D:\angularjs\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at cb (D:\angularjs\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
    at DestroyableTransform. (D:\angularjs\gulpfile.js:28:30)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at D:\angularjs\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:965:16
```